# How Do I Make A Perfect Uv Sphere For Water (Not For Equirectangular)

Tags: modeling, animation, uv, rigging

Hello so i have a water texture i'm trying to uv map to a sphere without hard lines and stuff i managed to unwrap it pretty good then my old version but there's still just 1 hard line in the middle how would i get rid of it take a look [image]

here's how the uv's look [image]

all i'm trying to do is get rid of that middle hard line if anyone knows please let me know thanks

Comment: The way you Unwrapped the sphere would require the texture to be tileable in a way that the circumference of the map would repeat somehow... I don't think that any tileable texture does that.

Comment: See if [this article](http://blog.michelanders.nl/2017/08/avoiding-repetition-artifacts-with.html) helps give you a solution.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=unwrap%20sphere

Comment: by painting and blurring over your assigned texture, when done be sure to save the modified bitmap

Comment: David how did you ever became a moderator ?, 
That is a solution and how people commonly do that.

Answer (score 1):

While in Edit mode, select one meridian at your choice. Press "Space" and write down "mark seam". Select one "rectangle" near the equator and connected to the seam you marked, and press "a" to select all, press "u" to bring the unwrap menu and select "follow active quads". You can leave on "length average" and press "Ok". You will get a new UV map with equirectangular projection, with this UV map selected, in the UV Image Editor, adjust the size to match the image, or leave it if the image is tileable.
An easier method (assuming that you are using cycles, and without the need of unwraping) is with a node setup like this:[image]
You can even try to build a seamless procedural sea image your self, and if you really need, bake the procedural image onto a a new image (it will get seamless on your sphere). You can try the following node setup:[image]

Comment: Tried that now it just makes the bottom and top look weird my original version looked better since there was only 1 sharp line in the middle. Here's the Blend File as well as the image so you can see what's going on http://puu.sh/xDVmt/8e4af94a67.zip i even highlighted the area with grease pencil so you can see

Answer (score 0):

A common workaround is: create a new UV with completely different seams, bake your texture to a new image with the new UVmap, edit the new texture in any 2D software to cover the seams.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your UV islands: you made a seem in the equator and unwraped it. Your two Islands arent connected where supposed to be, needing to rotating 1 of the UV islands until match. An easier way to work this around is to delete the bottom half of the sphere and to a mirror modifier on the Z axis. This process solves your issue but creates a strange mirrored area near the equator. I really believe it suites you the creation of the procedural texture as I mentioned on previous answer and bake it into a new image. In attach I send you your Blend file, with texture "fixed" to your UVmap, and a ball with a procedural texture (just need to bake): [image]

Comment: Here is a file, with a sphere like yours, with procedural texture, and a baked texture. Please note what I have done to the UVmap.[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3853" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3853/)

Comment: The Mirror Trick Fixed the issue thanks a lot also baking does fix it as well but it doesn't work on custom textures with that being said is the mirror trick the only solution? i mean even though it's a lot better then my original. it still creates strange mirrored area near the equator like you said see https://gyazo.com/96448aec209fef20c44de22ac6360788  noticable when you zoom in but it's still way better then before is there a fix for that area or this is the best it can get it's not that big of a deal but if there's a way might as well know

Comment: The problem of your ball is your UVmap. In order to dont get a noticeable seam, I would suggest to UV unwrap it as a equirectangular map and use a tileable texture. To fix the poles issue, you can search on how to get quadfaces there and correct the stretch manually. The real custom way, is to paint directly on the sphere, and or use procedural textures.